# Undo git checkout --orphan

Tags: git

I "mistakenly" checked-out my git repo as an orphan branch. Is there a way to revert this command ? I have not made any commits or even changed the repo any other way.

Comment: Just checkout to your normal branch as you normally do

Comment: Following the answer below, to delete the branch locally : git branch -D <anExistingBranch>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the branch has been created (without any parent or commit), I would reset it to the current branch it should have started from:

```
# check that your current branch is the orphan one
git branch

git reset <anExistingBranch>
# or
git checkout -B <anExistingBranch>
```

A commit done from there will be done in the new branch, with the HEAD from `<anExistingBranch>` as parent.
That would "un-orphan" your orphan branch.

(I assume this is about a new branch, since a `git checkout --orphan` on an existing branch would not work "`fatal: A branch named 'xxx' already exists`")

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. The question was how to undo the command which is answered by me and also the comment, just a simple checkout. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire Calling `git checkout --orphan` on an existing branch would not work "`fatal: A branch named 'xxx' already exists`". That is why I assumed we are talking about a new branch.: once the branch is created, a simple checkout would not change anything. A reset (or `git checkout -B`) is needed to move HEAD.

Comment: Nope, if you do `git checkout --orphan foo && git checkout master` leaves you in the exact same state you were before. A orphan checkout does not actually create the branch as there is no checkin yet that the branch could point to. Much the same as if you do `git init && git checkout -b foo && git add . && git commit -m foo` which leaves you with one branch called `foo` and no `master` branch because only the first commit would really create the branch.

Comment: Which was the question, if I may quote: `Is there a way to revert this command ?` :-)

Comment: @Vampire Again, agreed. I wanted to mention there is an alternative to a simple revert, which allows to start working on the new branch from the right starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Just check out the branch you want to be with a normal checkout.

Comment: It doesn't let met saying my Untracked files would be overwritten, `git checkout -f master` works (force)

Comment: Yeah, sure, if you have untracked files that would be overwritten, that is normal behavior. Also if you switch between normal branches. That is not specific to the situation in this question.

Answer (score -1):

git reflog -3 && echo see your previous commits

git checkout head@{1} && echo to checkout your previous commit